# Is it secure to use 3rd party apps like WASender for bulk WhatsApp messaging through WhatsApp web?

Tags: whatsapp

A client collects phone numbers through lead form on his website and he is hell-bent on sending WhatsApp instead of email. To build a solution from scratch is out of the question of after some research I came across Wasender, they claim to provide an API just that (`[How it Works][1]`).

They've got good reviews on the Chrome web store and all with a lot of users but I am not sure if it's safe. There's always some risk with small 3rd party integrations but has anyone worked with something like this? Is the data safe? If you have used something like this, is there a way the integration could bypass WhatsApp's encryption? Just don't wanna end up with the client's critical business info leaked.

Answer (score 1):

> ...  is there a way the integration could bypass WhatsApp's encryption?

It does not need to bypass any encryption. It is a browser extension and as such it has access to the messages the same way as the Whatsapp in the browser has - in fact, you grant the extension access to web.whatsapp.com and thus to all your messages since these are no longer encrypted in your browser.

> Is the data safe?

Which data, against what? The messages are send using your WhatsApp account. They might be changed by the extension before sending but they are delivered encrypted from your phone to the recipient. The extension could also read your existing messages. 
 I'm not saying that the extension does anything like this but it could based on the permission you grant. And even if it doesn't do this now it might do it later, or never, or instead send their own ads using your contacts ...
If you feel comfortable with this then it might be safe enough for you.

Comment: I agree with @Ullrich. Its a chrome extension. It can read html code and do the work for you.
I think it is just an automation built over top of wa.me open API. It does the job like a robot. doing clicks and sending messages.